# Java based signature does not match OpenSSL based signature

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, pkcs#1

I have a PKCS#1 RSA Key.

Using Java I generated a digital signature for a text file with the word, "hello". 
Reference for Java implementation I used:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step3.html

```
 Signature mysig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA","SUN");
 mysig.initSign(mykey); //mykey is the PKCS#1 RSA key
 mysig.update(data.getBytes()); //data is the text file with the word hello
 byte[] signdata = mysig.sign();
```

Using the SAME PKCS#1 RSA Key, I generated digital signature for the SAME file, using OpenSSL

```
 openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privatekey.pem -out signature.sign file.txt
```

Turns out that the digital signature generated by Java and OpenSSL does not match. Wondering why is that?

Comment: Did you correctly load the private key into Java? See [Load RSA public key from file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19387517/5221149).

Comment: Is `data` a string? You may have an encoding issue. I ran a quick test and what you've described works for me.

Comment: [Why are the RSA-SHA256 signatures I generate with OpenSSL and Java different?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13419201), [Signed message using openssl. Can't verify with Android/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31004847), [Different RSA signatures when using OpenSSL and Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34134848), etc.