# Why Does My Java Private Key Signature Not Match My Openssl Signature?

Tags: java, openssl, signature, sha256, private-key

So the signature that I'm getting from Java doesn't match what I'm getting in openssl.  Here's an example of what I'm doing:

In a terminal using openssl I'm doing this.

```
    echo +pkCdYME5SzI7A2PV0r8/8FqYGZyvTp+4DoGkdaMYRs= hash
    openssl dgst -sha256 -sign "private.key" -out hash.sha256 hash
    base64 < hash.sha256 > hash.bin
    cat hash.bin
    results posted below
```

Java Code: (hash matches the one I'm using for openssl)

```
    private String createSignature(String hash) throws ProductException {
      try {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(getPrivateKey());
        privateSignature.update(hash.getBytes(UTF_8));
        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
        String result = Base64.encodeBase64String(signature);
        System.out.println(result); //THIS RESULT SHOULD MATCH BUT DOESN'T
        return result;
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | SignatureException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new ProductException(Codes.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, e);
      }
    }   
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws ProductException {
      try {
        String key = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("private.key"));
        PemObject pem = new PemReader(new StringReader(key)).readPemObject();
        byte[] content = pem.getContent();
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);
      } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new ProductException(Codes.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, e);
      }
    }
```

PLEASE HELP!  I've scoured the interwebs and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My openssl signature = 
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

My Java Signature = 
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

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are the RSA-SHA256 signatures I generate with OpenSSL and Java different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419201/why-are-the-rsa-sha256-signatures-i-generate-with-openssl-and-java-different)

Comment: Yeah I've looked at that post.  Unfortunately I am still struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue comes from using `echo` for preparing an input to your signature function.
By default, `echo` appends a newline to whatever its output is, and the byte representing it messes up the signature.

Try `echo -n` that skips the newline and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this reply!  This very well might have been my problem.  I finally got my code working with the integrator I was working with, but never did get the above example to give me the input I was wanting.